# Are the walls of this closet load bearing?

Tags: load-bearing, closet

My back entryway has this closet that kinda sticks out. I would rather have an entryway bench there instead.
Just from glancing at this photo, do you think this is load bearing?
Directly underneath in the basement is the furnace, and directly above is the guest room. Neither of which seem to have any structural support in the same area.[image]

Comment: The window and door wall will be load bearing.  Both closet walls are too close to the load bearing walls, so unless extra unknown weight is above, I give 90% not load bearing

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell with 100% certainty.  It's *very* unlikely to be load-bearing.  At a stretch ...the builder ran out of joists but had some that were 2 feet too short, so built the closet, used the shorter joists, and added some two-foot ones across the closet.   I'm trying too hard right?  But if you want to be 100% sure, since your intention is to demolish the thing and you'll have to patch and paint anyway, start by making a hole in the closet ceiling and looking to see if my silly imaginary scenario is fact.  If it is, just patch up the closet ceiling crudely; it doesn't matter if it doesn't look perfect.  Otherwise keep smashing!